# How do I install the las2ogr tool from liblas in Windows using the osgeo4w installer?

Tags: gdal, lidar, liblas, las-files

I was wondering if anyone has used the LAS2OGR tool?  I heard about this from a previous post.  The webpage gives the usage: http://www.liblas.org/utilities/las2ogr.html

```
las2ogr -i mydata.las -o points.shp -f "ESRI Shapefile"
```

But I am wondering what I run it in?  I am on a Windows & box with FWTools 2.4.7 and it is coming up as an unrecognized tool.  When I open OSG4W (gdal 1.9.2 released 2012/10/08) las2ogr is not listed in the tool set.  Where should I be accessing this from?  Do I need to download a specific .exe or .dll and save it to the GDAL folder?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to install liblas from the Commandline_Utilities in the osgeo4w installer:

[image: installing liblas from osgeo4w installer]

Once that's done, it should be available via the osgeo4w terminal:
[image: las2ogr in osgeo4w terminal]

Comment: Thank you, I have done this now, but when I try to access las2ogr, it comes up as:

    Error: missing input paremeters

Comment: @ryangarnett Can you see las2ogr in the list of available tools inside the osgeo4w terminal?

Comment: Yes I can, that is the odd thing.  I read that I need to put in liblas, when I do, a new window opens, its: Administrator: libLAS OSGeo4W Shell

Comment: Do I need to manually add any environmental variables?

Comment: @ryangarnett That is strange. I didn't have to add any env variables. The las2ogr.exe is in my OSGeo4W\bin folder. That bin folder gets added to the %PATH% every time osgeo4w is ran so it should be finding it. What is the output from `las2ogr -h`? Does it give you a list of _options_?

Comment: @ryangarnett it looks like your first comment is a good clue. Tells me it'

Comment: ...s actually working. You just need to enter **parameters** now like the input/output file and -f for format like you have originally.

Comment: Yes the las2ogr -h works.  I guess it was my assumption that typing las2ogr would give the usage, like it does in FWTools